# Is sitting all day in anyway related to butt size?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat

I'm a programmer and I sit by the computer almost all day long, some days literally all day, and I heard that sitting all day is one reason why someone's butt can get bigger is that true? and if yes, what is the science behind it?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with exercise. Right now it reads as something off-topic as what we've defined to be our scope in the [faq].

Comment: I'm a programmer and spend 8 hours a day sitting (more or less). I don't have a big butt On the other hand, I don't over eat and go to the gym each morning.

Comment: A related question would be if sitting all day causes lordosis.

Comment: @Luciano Thanks, that's exactly what I was trying to describe,  I didn't know there was a medical term for it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how that could be true in a "specifically increases butt size" way.

It'll cause issues in several *other* significant ways, including an increased likelihood of slower metabolism, weight gain, and a wad of other health issues, which have been discussed to death in the blogosphere of late.

Specifically butt-reshaping, in a statistically-meaningful way? Doubt it. If you're particularly concerned, try a different chair style (ball, kneeling, etc.) or better yet, start alternating with a stand-up or tread-desk.

Comment: This seems like a lot of possibly educated opinion, but do you have anything to back it up?

Comment: @NathanWheeler Nope, which is why I specifically said "*I* don't see how".

Answer (score 2):

Long periods of pressure (i.e., how your posterior feels after 9 hrs in the chair) have lately been discovered to decrease blood flow and lead to lowered metabolic activity in the individual adipose cells in the affected region. Some speculation but no conclusive evidence that reducing blood flow to the adipocytes (fat cells) decreases the rate at which their lipid stores are burned as opposed to well perfused cells. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Do you have a link to that research? I'd love to see it.

Comment: Even if true, wouldn't that mean there is a lower chance of blood depositing fat in these areas as well?  Thus there wouldn't be any increase in buttox size, but no decrease in size either.